# Is it possible to use Terraform to recycle the azurerm_kubernetes_cluster service_principal:client_secret only

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to recycle the `service_principal:client_secret` value in an AKS Cluster which was provisioned by terraform using the documentation on [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html).

But, when I change the value of client_secret from `00000000000000000000000000000000` to `00000000000000000000000000000000new=` for example

```
service_principal {
  client_id     = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  client_secret = "00000000000000000000000000000000new"
}
```

Terraform doesn't honour the change:

I would have expected Terraform to notice that the client_secret is different and try to enact the change, but instead I see:

```
Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

I looked at the tfstate file and noticed that there is no value set for client_secret which I think is why terraform doesn't seem to recycle the key.

here is what it looks like:

```
service_principal.555555555.client_id: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
service_principal.555555555.client_secret: "",
```

Is this expected behavior, where terraform isn't reflecting a change when you only update the client_secret?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reset aks credentials with AZ cli: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/update-credentials

but not with terraform at this point in time.

Here's the exposed API call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/resetserviceprincipalprofile

you can even do this with arm templates, not with terraform